# iScroll 5 jumping to top of tha page when navigating views

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, iscroll

I am using iscroll 5 for my ios phonegap application in order to solve issues with the blinking of my fixed header. I am using a single page layout and each time the view changes I initialise a new myScroll variable. 
I've tested the outcome in my layout and I notice the following behaviour when navigating back and forth between views:
-after the animation the page is displayed in its previous scrolling position and it then jumps back to the top.

I've tried to use different timeout combination for creating the new myScoll variable but no luck.

**Update**: Here is the code

HTML

```
<body class="ios7" onload="onBodyLoad()"> <!-- native | ios7 -->
    <section id="view-home" class="active">
        <header>            
            <button class="left info" data-vin="view-about" data-sd="popin">                   </button>
            <h1>My app</h1>
            <button class="right map" data-vin="view-walks-map" data-sd="popin" onclick="onMapLoad('map_canvas')">
            </button>

        </header>
        <div class="scrollMask"></div>
        <div class="scrollWrap">
            <div class="scroll">
                <ul class="content">
                    <div class="homeTile">
                        <div class="tile" data-vin="view-walk1" data-sd="sl" onclick="galleryWalk1()">
                            <img src="images/walk-cover.png">
                            <div class="tileContent">
                                <h2>Walk title</h2>
                                <p>This is a walk description! Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di           Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato. Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato.</p>
                                <div class="transform-border-hairline"></div>
                                <ul class="metadata">
                                    <li class="fromLocation">Forio</li>
                                    <li class="toLocation">Lacco Ameno</li>
                                    <li class="lenght">3 km</li>
                                    <li class="difficulty1"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--Walk 1 page-->

    <section class="hidden" id="view-walk1">
        <header style="height: 81px;">

            <button class="left arrow" data-vin="view-home" data-sd="sr">
            </button>
            <h1>Walk name</h1>
            <button class="right compass-btn" data-vin="view-compass" data-sd="popin" onclick="loadCompass()">
            </button>
            <button class="right map" data-vin="view-walk1-map" data-sd="popin" onclick="onMapLoad('map_canvas_walk1')">
            </button>
            <div class="nav">
                <button id="btn1" class="active" data-vin="view-tab1Container">
                    <div class="label">Description</div>
                </button>
                <button id="btn2" data-vin="view-tab2Container">
                    <div class="label">Directions</div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="scrollMask"></div>
        <div class="scrollWrap">
            <div class="scroll">
                <ul class="content" style="margin-top: 85px;">

                    <div class="active" id="view-tab1Container">
                        <div class="tile walkTile">
                            <img src="images/walk-cover.png"  alt="walk image">
                            <div class="tileContent">
                                <p class="paddingT">This is a walk description! Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato. Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato.</p>
                                <p class="fromLocation fromLocationB">Forio</p>
                                <p class="toLocation toLocationB">Lacco Ameno</p>
                                <div class="transform-border-hairline"></div>
                                <ul class="metadata">
                                    <li class="duration">3 ore</li>
                                    <li class="slope">200 m</li>
                                    <li class="lenght">3 km</li>
                                    <li class="difficulty1"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="placeInterest">
                            <h2>Luoghi di interesse</h2>
                            <ul class="arrowed">
                                <div class="transform-border-hairline grey"></div>
                                <li data-vin="view-place1" data-sd="sl" onclick="galleryWalk2()">
                                    <div class="innerLi" >
                                        <div class="museum"> <span> Site of interest 1</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="no-border" data-sd="sl">
                                    <div class="innerLi">
                                        <div class="museum"> <span>Site of interest 1</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <div class="transform-border-hairline grey"></div>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="gallery">
                                <figure><a href="images/big/A-15.jpg"><img class="ml" src="images/thumbs/A-15.jpg" alt="Giullari senza Frontiere"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/A-18.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/A-18.jpg" alt="Giullari senza Frontiere"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/B-21.jpg"><img class="ml" src="images/thumbs/B-21.jpg" alt="Giullari senza Frontiere"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/B-24.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/B-24.jpg" alt="Giullari senza Frontiere"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/C-72.jpg"><img class="ml" src="images/thumbs/C-72.jpg" alt="Il Conte Schippa"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/C-12.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/C-12.jpg" alt="Il Conte Schippa"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/C-53.jpg"><img class="ml" src="images/thumbs/C-53.jpg" alt="Il Conte Schippa"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/C-33.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/C-33.jpg" alt="Il Conte Schippa"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/G-16.jpg"><img class="ml" src="images/thumbs/G-16.jpg" alt="I Giullari di Nessuno"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/G-87.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/G-87.jpg" alt="I Giullari di Nessuno"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/G-59.jpg"><img class="ml" src="images/thumbs/G-59.jpg" alt="I Giullari di Nessuno"></a></figure>
                                <figure><a href="images/big/G-65.jpg"><img src="images/thumbs/G-65.jpg" alt="I Giullari di Nessuno"></a></figure>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class=" hidden" id="view-tab2Container">   
                        <ol>
                            <li>This is a walk description! Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato. Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato.</li>
                            <li>This is a walk description! Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato. Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato.</li>
                            <li>This is a walk description! Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato. Una passeggiata indimenticabile alla scoperta del passato greco di Ischia unito alla visione di panorami mozzafiato.</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
scrollWrap {
    height: 100%;*/
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* Prevent native touch events on Windows */
    -ms-touch-action: none;

    /* Prevent the callout on tap-hold and text selection */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* Prevent text resize on orientation change, useful for web-apps */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -o-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;

}

.scroll {

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;

    /* Prevent elements to be highlighted on tap */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-color: rgb(229, 230, 224);
    /* Put the scroller into the HW Compositing layer right from the start */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
.scrollMask {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgb(229, 230, 224);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: -10px 0 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

section {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
function onBodyLoad()
{
    console.log("subscribing to the deviceready event");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    App.init();
    loadIscroll();
    console.log('firing iScroll');
    var screenHeight = screen.height;
    console.log(screenHeight);
    var scrollWrapArray = $$('.scrollWrap');
    for (var i = 0; i<scrollWrapArray.length; i++) scrollWrapArray[i].style.height = screenHeight 
    + 'px';

}

function loadIscroll (){
    var wrapper = document.querySelector('section.active .scrollWrap');
    console.log (wrapper);
    myScroll = new IScroll(wrapper, {
    });

}
var App = {
    init: function () {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);

        var tabbtns = $$('.nav button');
        for (var i = 0; i<tabbtns.length; i++) tabbtns[i].addEventListener('click', SwitchTabs, false);

        var navbtns = $$('header button.right, header button.left');
        for (var i = 0; i<navbtns.length; i++) navbtns[i].addEventListener('click', Slide, false);

        var listitems = $$('.homeTile div.tile');
        for (var i = 0; i<listitems.length; i++) listitems[i].addEventListener('click', Slide, false);

        var listitems2 = $$('.arrowed li');
        for (var i = 0; i<listitems2.length; i++) listitems2[i].addEventListener('click', Slide, false);

    }
};

function refreshIscroll () {
    myScroll.refresh();
    console.log('refreshed iscroll');
}


function onDeviceReady () {
    console.log("device ready event received");
}

var Slide = function (callback) {

    var vIn = $('#'+this.dataset.vin),
    vOut = $('section.active'),
    slideType = this.dataset.sd,
    onAnimationEnd = function () {
        vOut.classList.add('hidden');
        vIn.classList.add('active');
        vIn.classList.remove(slideOpts[slideType][0]);
        vOut.classList.remove(slideOpts[slideType][1]);
        vOut.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', onAnimationEnd, false);
        vOut.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
        console.log('animation ending');
    };
    console.log(slideType);
    console.log(vIn, vOut);
    vOut.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', onAnimationEnd, false);
    vOut.addEventListener('animationend',       onAnimationEnd);
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') {
        callback();
    }
    vOut.classList.remove('active');
    vIn.classList.remove('hidden');
    vIn.classList.add(slideOpts[slideType][0]);
    vOut.classList.add(slideOpts[slideType][1]);
    setTimeout(function () {
        refreshIscroll() 
    }, 600);
    myScroll.destroy();
    myScroll = null;
    console.log('destroying', myScroll);
    setTimeout(function () {
        loadIscroll() 
    }, 1000); 
    refreshIscroll();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the java script  `

> scrollTo(xpos,ypos)

method.